# (jog 10km, swim for five hours and eat five hot dogs) or (jogging 10km, swimming for five hours and eating five hot dogs)

Tags: tense

(1) If I want to, I'll do some things all in one day I have never done before: jog 10km, swim for five hours and eat five hot dogs.

(2) If I want to, I'll do some things all in one day I have never done before: jogging 10km, swimming for five hours and eating five hot dogs.

Which verb form is correct?

Comment: Both are fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the activities you mention as answers to the question "What will I do?"
You can say
*I will do some jogging*
or
*I will do jogging to lose weight.*

But for a specific running task, You would not say either
**I will do jogging 5 km.*
or
**I will jogging 5 km.*

The same answer applies to your original question. The bare form of the verb, rather than the gerund, fits better with "I'll do...", with each verb taking the place of "do":

*I'll jog 5 km, swim 5 miles, and eat five hot dogs.*